# How to get data from JSON in google sheets custom function

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, editor

I've been trying to do calculations based on prices on some crypto markets.
In the mean time I try and learn to write a custom function in the script editor that gets the ticker data.
So far, I can get the data with the following code;

```
    function getkrakenbtc() {
    var myUrl = "https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=XBTUSD";
    var jsonData = UrlFetchApp.fetch(myUrl);
    var jsonString = jsonData.getContentText();
    return jsonString;
    }
```

But this function gets all the data into one cell like this:

```
{
    "error": [],
    "result": {
        "XXBTZUSD": {
            "a": ["6828.90000", "1", "1.000"],
            "b": ["6822.40000", "3", "3.000"],
            "c": ["6828.30000", "0.45700000"],
            "v": ["8345.28377914", "11241.98107284"],
            "p": ["7079.63828", "7171.18596"],
            "t": [22419, 30041],
            "l": ["6751.00000", "6751.00000"],
            "h": ["7432.70000", "7529.70000"],
            "o": "7410.10000"
        }
    }
}
```

Then I then get the part that I want with the help of formulas. 
How can i get the a or b item of the above array using javascript?

Comment: You could convert you json string to an array, and then acces your data from this array

Comment: To get properties from a JavaScript object, use either dot or bracket notation, as necessary. If you have no clue what dot or bracket notation is for object property access, then you need to spend some time actually learning about JavaScript objects.

Comment: @tehhowch Actually I know little about notations and I already tried this:  return XRPUSDObject[0][2]  or  return  XRPUSDObject[1][2]  but both either gives me nothing on the sheet or #ERROR msg

Comment: I think I've found out:  "jsonString.result.XXBTZUSD.a[0]"  will do. Thank you for making me solve this :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert `jsonString` to an object with `JSON.parse()`. Then you can use dot or bracket notation to access the value you want. Here's an example.

```
function getAandB() {
  var jsonString = getkrakenbtc();
  var jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);
  var a = jsonObject["result"]["XXBTZUSD"]["a"];
  var b = jsonObject["result"]["XXBTZUSD"]["b"];
}

function getkrakenbtc() {
  var myUrl = "https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=XBTUSD";
  var jsonData = UrlFetchApp.fetch(myUrl);
  var jsonString = jsonData.getContentText();
  return jsonString;
}
```

If you want a custom function that can be used in the sheet, you can adapt the above according to the [Custom Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) reference documentation. For example:

```
/**
 * Get the array of values defined by 'ticker' and 'letter' from the selected cell, which contains valid JSON.
 *
 * @param {String} ticker Example: "XXBTZUSD"
 * @param {String} letter Example: "a" or "b"
 * @param {String} cell The cell containing the JSON
 * @return The array of values
 * @customfunction
 */
function GETVALUE(ticker, letter, cell) {
  var jsonObject = JSON.parse(cell);
  return jsonObject["result"][ticker][letter];
}
```

[image]

Comment: This worked, but instead of using another function I've done it in the same function adding only the 2 lines that u helped:  var jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);
  var a = jsonObject["result"]["XXBTZUSD"]["a"];  Thank you very much

Comment: Good. That's the essence of it. Please do mark the question as answered if you feel it's been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the function to get JSON value of any depth:

```
function getTextAsJson(JsonText, valuesArray)
{
  var node = JSON.parse(JsonText);  
  for (var i = 0, l = valuesArray.length; i < l; i++)
  {
    node = node[valuesArray[i]];     
  }    
  return node;    
}
```

Usage:

`=getTextAsJson(A1,{"result"; "XXBTZUSD"; "a"})`

[image]